# Count and remove duplicates from an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, replace, count

In Powershell I have the following array

```
foreach ($Record in $Records)
{ write-host $Record
}

@{car=OPEL; count=3}
@{car=BMW; count=2}
@{car=OPEL; count=8}
@{car=AUDI; count=3}
@{car=FORD; count=5}
@{car=FORD; count=4}
@{car=OPEL; count=4}
@{car=AUDI; count=5}
@{car=BMW; count=3}
```

I want to remove the duplicate elements by property "car", but to count and sum the property "count", so the above array becomes

```
@{car=OPEL; count=15}
@{car=BMW; count=5}
@{car=AUDI; count=8}
@{car=FORD; count=9}
```

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group the objects by their `car` property value, then use `Select-Object` to create new objects with the total count:

```
$records |Group-Object -Property car |Select-Object Name,@{Name='Count';Expression={($_.Group |Measure-Object Count -Sum).Sum}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Group-Object) and [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Measure-Object) as follows (of course, there *could be* a more elegant way):

```
$Records | Group-Object -Property car |
    ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            car = $_.Name;
            count = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property count -Sum).Sum
        }
    }
foreach ($Record in $RecordsSum) {
    Write-Host $Record
}
```

**Result**:

```
@{car=OPEL; count=15}
@{car=BMW; count=5}
@{car=AUDI; count=8}
@{car=FORD; count=9}
```